# Pseudorandom numbers - Get a sequence of number not close each others

Tags: calculus, algorithms, special-functions, random

I have this function inside a software:

```
a+(SeededRand(Round((SongTime-0.5+(Round(1000*c)))*1))-0.5)*b
```

it creates a pseudo-random numbers sequence inside the [0,1] interval.

The problem is that some values can be so close each others, such as :

```
6° number is 0.77569580078125
7° number is 0.781097412109375
```

is there a way to have a sequence of numbers not close each others? In the order of 0,2 distance, for example.

Hope the question is clear, else let me know and I'll try to explain it better...

Comment: Truly random numbers from $U(0,1)$ will behave like this, too. Is your concern that this "doesn't look random", or do you have a specific reason to want guaranteed large gaps in consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this, if you want (pseudo) random properties. Even if you randomly select from the numbers 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 there must be a positive probability that a number is the same as its neighbour in the generated sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want random numbers or maybe evenly-spaced numbers? The more evenly-spaced your numbers are, the less random those will be.

If you don't care how much random your numbers will be, you can always discard a newly selected point you and try again and again until you have found one that is not as close to the others. Other methods would involve introducing "safe zones", calculating the total size of it, selecting randomly and adjusting the result back into $[0,1]$ interval. There are yet other approaches, but remember, it will be less random, than just plain picking. Random numbers intrinsically form (random) clusters and it's just a popular human misconception that random should be evenly-spaced.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: I was typing something to this effect when you posted this, but just to add my 2 cents for the OP's benefit, here's a random sequence of 100 coin flips: $$HTTHTHHTTTHTTTTTHTTTTHTHT \\HHTTTHTTTHHTHHHHHHHHTHTHH \\HHHHTTTHTTTHTTHTHHTHHHHTT \\TTTTHHHHHHTHHTTHTHHHTTHTT$$ You might be surprised by how long the runs of heads and tails are, but that is an actual random sequence. When people are asked to write "random sequences", they tend to fail statistically by having runs that are too short on average. @markzzz: Your numbers looking too close together is the same kind of mistaken mental image.